# Can I set the value of a custom control programmatically in control project designer?

Tags: c#, winforms

Let's say I have a label in a custom control. In the constructor I set it's text value.

The label doesn't refresh. It does so only when in a client form.

How can I update this label on the custom control itself programmatically ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the text of the label accessible as a property of the Control:
(The getter is not necessary for your case, so you can leave that out if you don't want it)

```
public string LabelText
{
   get
   {
       return Label1.text;
   }
   set
   {
       Label1.text = value;
   }
}
```

This way the property will even show up in the designer of the control, or you can set it programmatically lik this:

```
MyControl.LabelText = "text";
```